# Existence of Euler path in $K_5$, the complete graph with five vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Construct an Eulerian path in $K_5$

I tried with the aid of the theorem:

> A graph contains an Eulerian path if and only if there are at most two vertices of odd degree.

But I became stuck while ending the walk at initial.

Comment: It is almost impossible to fail to construct an Eulerian path in $K_5$. If you start drawing, and put off drawing the final edge to the starting point for as long as possible, you will do it. How do you get stuck?

Comment: But, According to the definition, we have to grasp all the edges in the graph, right?

Comment: Visit each vertex once, so you are back where you started.  There are two unused edges at each vertex, so visit each vertex again, using only edges that haven't been traversed already.

Comment: Note that in addition to the condition of "at most two vertices of odd degree," an Eulerian path requires the graph to be connected.  Of course this is true of $K_5$.

Comment: Just a note about terminology (since it would appear that @RIYASUDHEENT.K is a beginner): what you're looking for should **not** be called a path, since it repeats vertices. The only things which may be referred to as Eulerian (at least in the context of your question) are *trails* and *circuits*. In particular, here you are looking for an Eulerian trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
If you put the five points as the vertices of a regular pentagon, the graph is a pentagon plus a five pointed star.  Start at any vertex, draw the pentagon to get back to where you started.  Now draw the five pointed star.  When you get back the second time, you have your path.  If the vertices are $ABCDE$ clockwise, you have $ABCDEACEBDA$